# Android doesn't recognize generate vCard .vcf?

Tags: php, android, vcf-vcard

I am dynamically generating .vcf files / vcards. The following setups work like as expected when browsing to the url:

mydomain.com/test//lookup.php?id=888

- pc / chrome browser
- mac / chrome browser
- iphone / safari browser

Problem is 
- android (5.0.2) / chrome browser, it only downloads the .vcf and even when i manual try to add the vcf the contact details are not stored in the android phones contacts

The downloadvcf function looks like this:

```
public function DownloadVcard() {
    header("Content-type: text/directory");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $this->fileName . ".vcf" . "");
    header("Pragma: public");

}
```

Any tips how to fix this?

Comment: could you elaborate about "it does not work", please ? any error output ? maybe you could try to download android sdk tools and use logcat to check if there is any output about your vcard import...

Comment: Start by using the correct MIME type (`text/vcard` assuming that your vCard supports a current specification). But, beyond that, please explain, in detail, what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: Hi alex, did you find any solution?